# How to mark select items as checked in a multiselect dropdown with optgroups laravel

Tags: php, select, laravel, laravel-4, multi-select

I am using this select dropdown plugin . I can get all the ids of the selected items in the dropdown during the store method. However during the edit method when ever i am trying to load the entity that has multiple values , i am unable to mark the items as checked in the dropdown.

Suppose I am working with schools and each school can belong to many categories so here is a belongsToMany relationship between the contacts and the categories. On the select dropdown create form, my categories are grouped in optgroup depending on which type they belong to... I have a oneToMany relationship between type and categories...
Down here is my code snippet on the create form...

```
<select class="form-control select-picker" name="categories[]" multiple="multiple" title="Choose one or more">
   @foreach ($types as $type)
   <optgroup label="{{ $type->name}}">
     <?php $type_categories = $type->categories;?>
        @foreach ($type_categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
   </optgroup>
   @endforeach
```

Now how can i populated the dropdown in edit mode while marking the selected values removing the optgroup because the code below works if i omit the optgroup

```
{{ Form::select('categories[]', App::make('Category')->lists('name', 'id'), $school->categories()->select('categories.id AS id')->lists('id'),['class' => 'form-control select-picker','multiple'])}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom `Form` extension for this:

```
Form::macro('categoriesSelect', function ($name, $types, $selected, $attributes) 
{
    $groups = [];

    foreach ($types as $type)
    {
        $groups[$type->name] = $type->categories->lists('name', 'id');
    }

    return Form::select($name, $groups, $selected, $attributes);
});
```

then just provide a collection of `Types` with `Categories`:

```
Form::categoriesSelect(
  'categories[]',
  App::make('Type')->with('categories')->get(),
  $school->categories()->select('categories.id AS id')->lists('id'),
  ['class' => 'form-control select-picker','multiple']
)
```

Note: I wouldn't call those queries in the blade template, but that's another story.